# Gephi preview export pdf cuts off label at left and right margin

Tags: export, gephi, sna

I would like to export a SVG/PDF/PNG from the preview tab in Gephi. The exported network includes all the nodes, but cuts off the node labels on the left and right sides. How can I get an exported pdf which does not cut off the labels?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to adjust the size of the output by controlling the **Options**. For example if you save in PNG format you see the following dialog where you should click at the bottom right corner

[image: Save as PNG dialog]

Which brings you to the following dialog where you adjust the image width

[image]

You have to play a little bit with the settings to see what works well for you